# How to search for an invalid character which is neither present in Spanish alphabet nor in English alphabet?

Tags: notepad++

I have a 2000 lines of file of SQL codes which is having some junk characters. By junk I mean, these characters do not belong to either Spanish or English alphabet. In notepad++, is there any way to search invalid character like this?

For example, consider the following line,

```
UPDATE table A SET some_string = 'No se encontrÃ³ un producto fÃ¬sico para el plan ingresado' WHERE some_ID = 'XYZ001'
```

Here the special characters are ³ and ¬ but Ã is not as it is a valid Spanish character.

If there is any other way, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: Why would you expect Notepad++ to know what characters are not appropriate for English or Spanish, as long as those characters are in the selected character set?

Comment: @KenWhite, If it is not defined like that, fine. So is there any workaround to do so? That's all I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any references to the letter ã/Ã being in the Spanish language. What you have here is a case of encoding error, and the garbage letters is a result thereof. To fix do like so:

```
1. Open a new empty document, Ctrl+N.
2. Change the encoding to cp1252 (Encoding -> Character sets -> Western European -> Windows-1252.
3. Paste your original text ("... encontrÃ³...")
4. Change encoding to UTF-8 (Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8).
```

The resulting string is "... se encontró un producto fìsico para...", which btw does not contain ã/Ã.

#### Alternative

If you however instead want to find the "Spanish" characters, like your question suggest, do like so:

```
Regex search:  [^\x00-\x7FãáéíñóúüÃÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ¿¡]
```

(Notepad++ ships with built-in [PCRE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) support.) The above expression will match *all* non-ASCII, non-"Spanish" characters, like the two characters ³, and ¬ you list above.